# php accessing null-variable as array by key

Tags: php, arrays

I'm using php 7.2.25

I don't understand the following code:

```
$x = [];
var_dump($x);
var_dump($x['X']);

$y = null;
var_dump($y);
var_dump($y['Y']);
```

output:

```
array(0) {
}
Notice:  Undefined index: X on line
NULL
NULL
NULL
```

Why accessing `$y['Y']` is just null without any notice?
How to receive any notice here?

Link: http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/2855ea8caca485174a84fd8d268b02725493392f

Comment: Looks like it changed in 7.4.0 to issue _Notice: Trying to access array offset on value of type null_ https://3v4l.org/8Rqod

Comment: So it's basically an old bug that has recently been fixed.

Comment: So the answer will be "update your PHP version"